# Mount SMB storage on shiled TV accross subnet

Tags: nvidia-shield, cifs

I have a setup like this :

```
[Shield TV 2015] 10.10.2.112 <---> [OpenWRT Router] <---> [Synology SMB Share] 10.10.3.11
```

I want to be able to access all my NAS files with any apps on the shield TV, so, I want to mount permanantly  the SMB share on the Shield.

So after confirming the connection was router correctly usig solid explorer integrated smb client, I went into the shield settings > Storage > add new network storage and inputed the NAS path (\10.10.3.11\Public) and the associated credentials.

However, it can't mount it, and according to logcat, it can't find the NAS netbios name locally, which is normal as it's in another subnet, but abnormal as I inputed it by IP.

Moving the nas to the main subnet is out of the question for multiple reason.

In the end, is there a way to force the mount with just the IP ?

I'm open to all suggestion, even root or scripts ones.

Comment: How are you trying to mount it what detailed steps? Have you tried to mount from a command prompt? Or does solid explorer just have a mount button? The basic syntax to the basic mount command: `mount -t cifs //<server>/<share> <mountpoint>`. Each component needs its own attention. Example: `mount -t cifs //192.168.0.123/Documents /mnt/nas` maybe applicable WIN article on protocol and troubleshooting netbios name resolution issues: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/172218/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order Umm, also if NetBIOS via TCP/IP is not enabled, afaik IP will not work.